# Two overlapping images on the bottom of page

Tags: html, css, position, positioning

I need 2 overlapping images always shown on the bottom of the page, but not with `position:fixed`:

```
<div class="images">
    <img src="img1.jpg" class="image1" />
    <img src="img2.jpg" class="image2" />
</div>
```

I have tried this:

```
    img.image1, img.image2 {position: absolute; right:5px; bottom:5px;}
    img.image2 {z-index:10;}
```

which works fine if the page has no scrollbars

**SOLVED:** with `float` + `position:relative`

Comment: Can you explain the contempt against `position:fixed` ?

Comment: *"always shown on the bottom of the page"* - that's what `position:fixed` is for.

Comment: Except when "the bottom of the page" is not the same as "the bottom of the window".

Answer (score 0):

Position the outer div as fixed to bottom. Then use absolute for inner images.

```
.images { position:fixed; bottom:0; }
.images > img { position:absolute; bottom:5px; right:5px;}
```

Comment: with `fixed` the images are shown always on the bottom of the window but what i need is to be on the bottom of the page

Comment: then simply use that `div.images` at the end of markup? Inside footer div maybe, or you'll have to resort to Javascript